# How do I transition to legit freelancing, coming from a background of unethical projects?

Tags: electrical-engineering, ethics

I am a recent electronics engineering graduate, currently legally working as an embedded software engineer in a company.

In the future, I would like to become a freelancer, like signing up on a freelancing website and getting hired to do real projects.

Currently, as a side/weekend gig, I help engineering students with their diploma projects. It's obviously illegal but it's a very common practice around here. But frankly, it's a great opportunity for me to earn good money and learn my trade with real hands-on experience.

In the future, when looking for real customers, they will likely ask for a portfolio of my work. What am I going to show them? Some diploma projects of random people that I supposedly made? I'm afraid that would look very unprofessional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you in the USA there are couple of good ways to start building a profile.

- Volunteer at your local [FIRST robotics](https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/frc) team. This is good place to get started learning new skills and using current skills
- Be an active member of the communities such as [engineering stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions) where you can start building an online profile of you skills. You can asked embedded engineering type of question as well as answer engineering questions.
- You can contribute to open source projects, through platforms such as github.
- Solving a problem such as [Which kind of accelerometer/vibration sensor are suitable for sensing vibration of building floor caused by human foot strike?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31770/which-kind-of-accelerometer-vibration-sensor-are-suitable-for-sensing-vibration) in open source platform help build a technical profile.
- Sharing you solutions via platform such as youtube, or other social media platform can help build a technical profile.
- [Par Scholas](https://perscholas.org/) is great place to volunteer to share your technical skills, learn new skills and a build a technical project portfolio
- [Turing School of Software and Design](https://turing.io/) is another good place to start building a technical profile.

References:

- [How Tech Pros Can Volunteer in Fun Ways](https://insights.dice.com/2017/01/11/tech-pros-volunteer-fun-ways/)
- [Year up](https://www.yearup.org/about-us/vision-mission-values/?location=national-us/)
- [Chick Tech](https://chicktech.org)
- [Tech Bridge Girls](https://techbridgegirls.org/)
- [10 Volunteer Opportunities For Tech Professionals To Transform Their Communities](https://www.bizible.com/blog/volunteer-opportunities-for-tech-professionals)

Comment: I really like this answer. I will look into some pro bono projects I can contribute to. Thank you!